# Linq extension include() error => Address

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm adding a detail page to my club controller. The code looks like this. I'm trying to add SQL [InvalidCastException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ5nk.png)join in the public IActionResult Detail(int id) based on the way I've modeled the data in the app. [Club Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugLll.png)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RunGroupWebApp.Data;
using RunGroupWebApp.Models;

namespace RunGroupWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class ClubController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ClubController(ApplicationDbContext context) 
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Club> clubs = _context.Clubs.ToList();
            return View(clubs);
        }

        public IActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
            Club club = _context.Clubs.Include(a => a.Address).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            return View(club);
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried to add Convert String to Int Using Int32.Parse() example

```
public IActionResult Detail(int id)
{
    var Address = "id";
    var number = 0;

    number = int.Parse(Address);
    Console.WriteLine($"Converted '{Address}' to {number} using 'int.Parse()'");
    Club club = _context.Clubs.Include(a => a.Address).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    return View(club);
}
```

I currently get a System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct formation. Am I on the right track with this attempt to do a conversion?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think you've got right excepttion while trying to convert `"id"` to integer. en

Comment: Please add your `Address` class for more details

Comment: If the `id` parameter is already an `int`, why do you need to convert it? If you are just testing code that converts `id` to a `string` and back, perhaps you meant to write `var Address = $"{id}";` or `var Address = id.ToString();`.